# laravel 5.1 : how can i have two wherePivot in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I need check two where conditions on a pivot table. I know that I can check one condition with this:

```
$dis = $user->discounts()->wherePivot('used_for_id', '=', null)
```

However, I want two where conditions. When I use `orWherePivot`, the two where conditions are `OR`ed together, but I want them to be `AND`ed together.

```
$whereData = [
    ['id', "=", $discountId],
    ['used_for_id', "=", null]
];
```

Comment: only point I like add for my question :

not correct "id" in wherePivot because there is id for default in where . I change that to ->wherePivot('discount_id', $discountId)->wherePivot('used_for_type', null) and work correct!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wherePivot()` works the same as a normal `where()` method; you can just chain on the second `wherePivot()` condition and it will be `AND`ed with the previous conditions:

```
$dis = $user
    ->discounts()
    ->wherePivot('id', '=', $discountId)
    ->wherePivot('used_for_id', '=', null)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

The wherePivot function definition is given below. So u can use $boolean variable as 'or' and 'and' for joining condition

```
public function wherePivot($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and') {   
  //code   
}   

 $dis = $user->discounts()->wherePivot('column', '=', null,'and')      
        ->wherePivot('column', '=', null,'or')       
        ->wherePivot('column', '=', null,'and')     
        ->get();
```

Comment: `orWherePivot()` is a shortcut method for calling `wherePivot()` with "or" as the last parameter. OP said this is not what they want.